# Specific strategy for Order decks when playing the "Death from Above" trial

Tags: scrolls

I don't have a lot of time, so I only get to play 1 or 2 rounds a day.  I'm curious, has anyone found an effective strategy agains the "easy" trial, *Death from Above*?

My problem is that the lobbers are to powerful to be taken out in the first few turns.  Furthermore, the pre-constructed order deck tends to have a lot of units that can't stand to many hits from the 3 lobbers that the opponent starts with.  So, after sacrificing a few scrolls for some resources and then finally getting a couple units on the board, they are destroyed before I can enhance them or they get a chance to attack.  If they do attack, some how my opponent manages to heal them.

It's a quick, vicious cycle and I can not beat this EASY trial!

I feel like I'm missing something.  If this is suppose to be "easy", what am I doing wrong.  FYI, I've found [GrumpyCat's YouTube video on Order strategy](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kOYuekF5pAU).  It's helped me a lot with all my other trials and AI battles but this one trial has been painfully difficult.

Does anyone have any specific suggestions for *Death from Above*?

Comment: You mention a specific video on YouTube... would you mind providing an actual link?

Comment: If I get a moment tonight, I'll try to update my post with a link to the video.

Comment: Ok, I updated the post.  The referenced video is now linked in the text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer - Just wait, stack cards and wait. They may put down 1 or 2 guys that can damage your relics but they will fill all the other lanes with structures that cant attack your idols.

I literally went about 40-50 rounds (can't recall exactly) getting about 30+ resources. When I finally had all the cards I wanted, I had the following units:

- Blessing of Haste x2
- Focus x3
- Skirmishers x4 (there are 2 types of skirmishers)
- General x1
- Vanguard x1
- Plate Armor x2
- Frost Wind x1
- Haboinks x2
- Decimate x3 (Not in the starter deck)

The scary part comes next, you will play your General and Vangaurd in a row together pop Plate armor on them and use Frost wind on the enemies in direct line with them to make sure they dont hit you. wait one turn, Hope your General and Vangaurd survive 1 health or more doesn't matter you win if they survive. Put down all four of your Skirmishers adjacent to your General then use both blessing of hastes on your General to bring it's Cooldown to 0 which at the same time will bring all your skirmishers and vangaurds Cooldown to 0. Now you play everything you got to increase damage so that you destroy everything in the three rows. Make sure you place spells wisely so as to not waste damage on idols your goal is to destroy everything so that 3 turns later you win.

It takes patience but it feels o so good after putting them in the dirt. This has worked on 2 occasions in the trials against Energy decks. A serious flaw in AI in my opinion.

Comment: Oko, I'll give you the answer mark once I get to try out this strategy.  Yes, I had a hunch that "waiting and stacking resources" was the way to go.  Still, this is a bit ridiculous.  This would be a horrible strategy in just about any other context.

Comment: @RLH yah, something that needs to be balanced for sure.

Comment: I ended up using a similar strategy, but instead focused all of my resources on one skirmisher. Once he gets a couple of plate mails and the vengeance veil he becomes a monster for cutting down whole rows of enemies

Answer (score 0):

The trick for this challenge is to have safe places. The canons can't be moved at first, so they fire at the same place each round/two rounds.

If you have to, use cards to move artillery to some other square to limit its area of effect.

Be sure to have a possibility to move the machine priest to kill them. They can heal and move the machines. Use the first round to build up strong units that can rush heavy structure. I had good use of crossbowmen with buffs. Keep in mind that each artillery have 4 to 6 health points. Protect your relentless units, they will also help you a lot.

Beware of the few creatures there is in the deck, they can hit your idols. Try to keep spiky units and structure to deal with these.

It is a good thing to keep the units on the opposing side at a minimum, his game can really snowball quickly.

When you can spawn your general(s) with plating, things should be easier.